# Convert a string containing a python list to a javasctipt array

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, string

I have this string:

> items = "['item1', 'item2']"

i need it to be a javascript array like this:

> items = ['item1', 'item2']

i try this and it works:

> items.replace("]","").replace("[","").replaceAll("'","").split(",");

and the result I obtained was as expected:

> ['item1', 'item2']

The question is: can the same be done in a simpler way?

Comment: easiest way: `eval(items)` or `JSON.parse(items.replace(/'/g, '"'))`

Comment: Required reading for `eval`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil

Comment: Yeah, don't use `eval`, but `JSON.parse` is the way to go for stuff like this.

Comment: @MartinV please check my solution when you have a chance. It uses a regex expression to make the replacement simpler and then `JSON.parse()` to interpret the final result as JSON data.

Comment: @ChrisG eval(items) was the solution!, thank you!

Comment: *The question is: can the same be done in a simpler way?* - if you can change the Python side, instead of just stringifying your list, use [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this very simply using a regex text replacement and `JSON.parse()`:

```js
const items = "['item1', 'item2']";

const array = JSON.parse(items.replace(/'/g, '\"'));

console.log(array);
```

If you would like to avoid `JSON.parse()` altogether, we can fine-tune the text replacement and use the `.split()` method like this:

```js
const items = "['item1', 'item2']";

const array = items.replace(/\[|\]|\s|'/g,'').split(',');

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Thanks @Brandon McConnell! for your answer. Sorry but "items =" is the variable assignment, I did not specify.

Comment: Three examples, and none of them matches OP's actual input data...! :D

Comment: @MartinV No worries! That makes this even simpler. I’ll make this change and update my answer shortly.

Comment: @MartinV I corrected my solution per your clarification. Please check when you have a chance.